# Authentication prompt before filling passwords in Microsoft Edge not working on Ubuntu

Tags: 20.04, 22.04, password, browser, microsoft

I have been using Microsoft Edge on my Ubuntu machines since they released a stable version for Linux. I am having one major security issue there though - for some reason the option to prompt for a system/primary password when filling a saved password doesn't work for me in Ubuntu.

Neither of these options work:

- *Prompt for the device password before filling website password* --> It is completely ignored and the passwords are being filled automatically regardless.
- *Prompt for the custom primary password before filling website password* --> When I select this option, it shows a prompt to create the custom password, but it doesn't let me save it.

This is only happening for me on my two laptops using Ubuntu. It works on Windows. Now my question is, whether it is a settings issue, or whether Ubuntu just doesn't support this functionality.

OS: Ubuntu 20.04 & 22.04
Edge version 115.0.1901.203 (and all previous versions since the stable release)